# Getting sql results into an array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My php crashes without an error because of the following code:

```
//print some html

$server = "localhost"; $user = "iremovedthis"; $pass = "iremovedthis";
$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass);
if ($connection->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connection->connect_error);
    exit(); }

$game_query = "SELECT * FROM games LIMIT 9;";
$game_query_result = $connection->query($game_query);
$row = $game_query_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//print more html
```

I'm trying to put the SQL result into an array.

If i comment the last line (starting with $row), my PHP keeps nicely printing HTML, but if i include the last line, it only outputs the HTML before my code and it doesn't give me a print error.

I seem have followed the PHP manual to a tee, anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: What do you mean by `crashes`? Have you checked your error logs? Is error reporting on? What is the result of `$game_query_result`?

Comment: You could try telling the connection what database you would like it to connect to!

Comment: did you check what `$connection->connect_error` says after query call?

Comment: I mean it stops outputting html, without giving me any error.  I'm pretty sure error reporting was already on. Adding "error_reporting(E_ALL);" to the top of the code doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly isn't giving a query pointing to database "games" enough?

Comment: Did you check the PHP error log? If you take a look at php.ini configuration file, you will see the path where the errors are logged. Go check that file, because any PHP crash would print an exception in this file.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli_connect()` needs to be told what database you want to connect to. Remember MYSQL can run 100's of databases simaltaneously.

```
$server = "localhost"; 
$user = "iremovedthis"; 
$pass = "iremovedthis";
$TheDatabase = 'mydb'; // of whatever you called your database

$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $TheDatabase);
```

> [The PHP manual for mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

RE: Your comment

*isn't giving a query pointing to database "games" enough?*

`games` is a table name, and not a database. Tables exist in databases, databases exist within a MySQL instance, A single MYSQL instance manages multiple databases. So in short, NO!

Comment: The old mysqli method didnt use to require a database, stupid mistake on my part. It's fixed now, thanks again.

Comment: RE: your RE: ah, im a bit rusty on php so hence the confusion.

Comment: I had a feeling you were probably coming from a `mysql_` background. Unfortunately the conversion to `mysqli_` is not just a case of adding the `i` to the `mysql_` api